# Stripe- Cancel recurring contribution

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, contributions, recurring-contributions, stripe

In testing CiviCRM/Stripe, we setup a recurring contribution and let it run for two months and then attempted to cancel it via the link in the email sent to the donor.

This resulted in the recurring payment being cancelled in CiviCRM but not in Stripe, so that the user will continue to be billed until someone logs into our Stripe account and manually ends the recurring payments (and no notification was giving to us on the admin side that someone attempted to cancel their 'subscription').

Our previous solution, using a Drupal module to handle recurring payments, allowed for seamless cancellations of recurring payments with Stripe. (We are running D7 and have installed the latest CiviCRM and Stripe extension)

Is this functionality working in Stripe?  I am assuming it is and that we missed something in the setup as it does not seem that Stripe would be a viable option if donors are unable to cancel their recurring contributions.

Thank you for any insight.

Rachel

Comment: Did you found any solution, I am facing same problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way to cancel recurring contributions when using the stipe extension is to cancel to recurring contribution in stripe. Stripe then sends that event to CiviCRM and the record is updated.

However it might be worth looking at this pull request to the stripe extension which claims to allow the behavior you are looking for.
https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/241

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is now possible to cancel from within CiviCRM. Would be helpful to update this answer or add a new one.